# Windows Phone 8.1 - BackgroundTransfer Invalid content length

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, websphere, background-transfer

I'm using background transfer (BTS) in one of our project (Windows Phone 8.1, BackgroudUploader, BackgroundDownloader, etc). The phone app sends pictures and documents to a Jave EE webapp, hosted on WebSphere Application Server. Sometimes we got the following error from the server: java.io.IOException: SRVE0080E: Invalid content length at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.finish(HttpInputStream.java:183), which means something is wrong with the Content-Length HTTP header calculation. This value is calculated automatically by the BTS API.

Is there any way to fix this issue, or this is a bug in BTS?

Comment: Impossible to tell who is at fault until you can capture the data.